# How to resolve the "Access to the path..." error?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

In my asp.net application, I have an xml file in this path:

```
~/Admin/App_Data/myXmlFile.xml
```

When I try inserting/deleting or updating on this file, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Access to the path ... is denied.
```

How could I resolve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Not the best question - what have you already tried?

Comment: Post complete stack trace. May be you need to set file permission for IIS_USER.

Comment: Also, post the code that is using that xml file path.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like similar to what I had faced a while back. I had a similar problem when website was hosted at `C:\Users\UserName\Documents\My Web Sites`. It was because with `Windows Vista` or `Windows 7` it requires Administration Privilege to update anything inside `C:\` (drive where your OS is installed).

Your problem looks like pretty match to that, try hosting your website on different location to diagnose if this is the case.